# jquery datepicker not disabled after setting mindate and maxdate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I have a datepicker and I set `minDate` to `0` and `maxDate` to `'+1m'`. But nothing got changed and I am able to select all dates.

```
minDate: 0, // The earliest selectable date, or null for no limit
maxDate: '+1m', // The latest selectable date, or null for no limit
```

When I made this change in `jquery-ui.js`, I am able to use the form and datepicker opens, but nothing was disabled.

Also I did the same from my html:

```
$(function () {
  $("#datepicker, #datepicker1, #datepicker2, #datepicker3").datepicker(maxDate:'+1m', minDate: 0);
});
```

Now not even the datepicker is opening.

Also I tried making the `minDate` and `maxDate` in `jquery-ui.js` file as comment. Still no datepicker is opening up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not change anything in `Jquery-ui.js`

You have the syntax error, as you missed `{` with `datepicker`

Declare the datepicker as below:

```
$(function() {

       $("#datepicker,#datepicker1,#datepicker2,#datepicker3").datepicker({ 
        minDate: 0,
        maxDate: '+1m',
    });

});
```

Comment: yes, you missed {}... I have added that in my updated answer

Comment: BTW I have a timewdiget, can I apply something like this in that? Like limiting the time between say some 8 AM and 8 PM

Comment: Which time picker you have used? Share the sample code for that, so I can help you

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying is syntactically incorrect. You need to pass an object (notice the braces inside the function call) to the `datepicker` method:

```
$(function () {
  $("#datepicker, #datepicker1, #datepicker2, #datepicker3").datepicker({ maxDate:'+1m', minDate: 0 });
});
```

Make sure that the selectors represent correct elements on your HTML page. Also, you don't need to change anything in jQuery UI's library to get this work.